# unfortunately project has closed in onclick method

Tags: android

Here is my image [image of my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGzXR.png)

8 is the left most number. tick mark has gameState function on click. Here below is the code. if 8 is in left side when i press tick mark project is unfortunately closed. if 8 comes on the right side and no empty space in those 9 buttons and empty space on left side and if i press tick mark project is not closing. please help.

when 8 comes to right and occupy the place of 27 so the left most button becomes empty,if i press tick mark game is working fine.If 8 remains on the left side ,if i press tick mark unfotunately project has closed. –

Here is the code

```
public void gameState(View view) {


    String button1Text = button[0].getText().toString();
    String button2Text = button[1].getText().toString();
    String button3Text = button[2].getText().toString();
    String button4Text = button[3].getText().toString();
    String button5Text = button[4].getText().toString();
    String button6Text = button[5].getText().toString();
    String button7Text = button[6].getText().toString();
    String button8Text = button[7].getText().toString();
    String button9Text = button[8].getText().toString();


    String aa = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button1Text) + Integer.parseInt(button2Text));
    String bb = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button4Text) + Integer.parseInt(button5Text));
    String cc = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button7Text) + Integer.parseInt(button8Text));
    String dd = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button1Text) + Integer.parseInt(button4Text));
    String ee = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button2Text) + Integer.parseInt(button5Text));
    String ff = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button3Text) + Integer.parseInt(button6Text));






    if (aa.equals(button3Text)&&bb.equals(button6Text)&& cc.equals(button9Text)&&
            dd.equals(button7Text)&& ee.equals(button8Text)&&ff.equals(button9Text)) {

        score += 100;
        numberofQuestions++;
        pointstextView.setText(Integer.toString(score) + "/" + Integer.toString(numberofQuestions));
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            button[j].setText("");

        }
        RightButton.setText("");
        generateQuestion();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat and tell us which line causes the app to crash.

Comment: when 8 comes to right and occupy the place of 27 so the left most button becomes empty,if i press tick mark game is working fine.If 8 remains on the left side ,if i press tick mark unfotunately project has closed.

Comment: As a side note, you should use an array for the Strings.

Comment: Also how do you initialize the button array?

Comment: http://codepaste.net/o5n4a8. this is my whole code

Comment: We need the error message, not more code.

Comment: ok i will paste the error

Comment: http://codepaste.net/v4dfgf.  This is the error

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: @Code Apprentice help me

Comment: I'll be glad to when you edit your question to provide the additional information I requested.

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs it seems that you are trying to convert empty string ( i.e. "") to Integer in file SecondActivity.java at line no. 717 which is causing the crash.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
                                                                                at com.example.personal.numbermania.SecondActivity.gameState(SecondActivity.java:717)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
```

Check this and add proper exception handling.